# "from src import *" dynamic import for all functions in a package or subpackage

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, importerror

**Goal:**
I want to be able to dynamically import all functions in a sub-package with 'a direct call'

**Usage:**
my project:

```
project/
|-- main.py
|-- src/
|---- __init__.py
|---- foo.py
|---- bar.py
```

`foo.py` has just one function:

```
def foo_funct(): 
    print("foo")
```

`bar.py` has just one function:

```
def bar_funct():
    print("bar")
```

and finally `main.py`:

```
from src import * 
(...)
foo_funct()
bar_funct()
(...)
```

**Comments:**

1. if my `__init__.py` is something like this

   ```
   import os 
   __all__ = [i.replace(".py", "") for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()+"/src/") if "__" not in i]
   ```

   I will be able to call `foo.foo_funct()` or `bar.bar_funct()` but not `foo_funct()` or `bar_funct()`
2. if my `__init__.py` is something like this:

   ```
   from src.foo import *
   from src.bar import *
   ```

   I will be able to call `foo_funct()` or `bar_funct()` but for each new sub package I will have to modify my `__init__.py`
3. Assuming that `from src import *` is not the most pythonic method, and assuming that it could be very dangerous to have direct calls due to possible naming conflicts such as `a.tree_funct()` and `b.tree_funct()`,  is there any method to reach my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to keep things explicit, and just import names that are part of the package API into `__init__` explicitly. Your project won't change so rapidly that dynamically importing everything into the `__init__.py` is going to be a time saver.

But if you want to do this, then you have a few options here. If you need to support Python versions older than 3.7, then you can update the package namespace by poking at the [`globals()` dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals). List all `.py` files and import them using [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) (or with [`__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) if you need to support Python versions before 2.7):

```
__all__ = []

def _load_all_submodules():
    from pathlib import Path
    from importlib import import_module

    g = globals()
    package_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
    for pyfile in package_path.glob('*.py'):
        module_name = pyfile.stem
        if module_name == '__init__':
            continue
        module = import_module(f'.{module_name}', __package__)
        names = getattr(
            module, '__all__', 
            (n for n in dir(module) if n[:1] != '_'))
        for name in names:
            g[name] = getattr(module, name)
            __all__.append(name)

_load_all_submodules()
del _load_all_submodules
```

The above keeps the namespace clean; after the `_load_all_submodules()` function has run it is removed from the package. It uses the `__file__` global to determine the current path and finds any sibling `.py` files from there.

If you only need to support Python 3.7 and up, you can define [module-level `__getattr__()` and `__dir__()` functions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-562-customization-of-access-to-module-attributes) to implement dynamic lookups.

Using those hooks in your package `__init__.py` file could look like:

```
def _find_submodules():
    from pathlib import Path
    from importlib import import_module

    package_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
    return tuple(p.stem for p in package_path.glob('*.py') if p.stem != '__init__')

__submodules__ = _find_submodules()
del _find_submodules


def __dir__():
    from importlib import import_module
    names = []
    for module_name in __submodules__:
        module = import_module(f'.{module_name}', __package__)
        try:
            names += module.__all__
        except AttributeError:
            names += (n for n in dir(module) if n[:1] != '_')
    return sorted(names)


__all__ = __dir__()


def __getattr__(name):
    from importlib import import_module
    for module_name in __submodules__:
        module = import_module(f'.{module_name}', __package__)
        try:
            # cache the attribute so future imports don't call __getattr__ again
            obj = getattr(module, name)
            globals()[name] = obj
            return obj
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    raise AttributeError(name)
```